# Replacing an arrow with an inclusion symbol in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Instead of an arrow from one place to another, I'd like to have the `\subseteq` symbol. More specifically, the `\subseteq` symbol rotated, which I believe can be rendered `\rotatebox{90}{$\subseteq$}` .

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz}          
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
 {
   G & H \\
    G/\ker \varphi & \mbox{Im} \varphi \\};     
 \path[-stealth]
(m-1-1) edge node [left] {$q$} (m-2-1)
        edge node [above] {$\varphi$} (m-1-2)   
 edge node [above] {$\hat{\varphi}$} (m-2-2)
(m-2-1) edge node [below] {$\overline{\varphi}$} (m-2-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, what I'd like to do is instead of having an arrow representing a map from the lower right node to the upper right node, I want the set inclusion symbol to show the relationship between the sets in question.

Thanks!

Comment: How are `\im` and `\ol` defined? Without that your example is not compilable.

Comment: `(m-2-2) edge[draw=none] node [sloped] {$\subseteq$} (m-1-2)`? By the way, do you know [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)/[tag:tikz-cd]?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, that worked perfectly, thanks! I know of tikz-cd, but one of the resources I have been using to make my diagrams mentioned that matrix was more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an edge that is not drawn (or a `\path` with `--`) and place a node on that edge/path that is `sloped` with the content `\subseteq`.

For comparison, I made the same diagram with [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

To your original diagram I added the `auto` option to make the placement of nodes along the path easier which needs to be disabled again for our special node.

If you want to avoid writing that lengthy

```
(m-2-2) edge[draw=none]
             node [sloped, auto=false,
              allow upside down] {$\subseteq$} (m-1-2);
```

you can use a special style that can do this. For `tikz-cd` a slightly different style can be defined too. See the second code example for this.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass[class=amsart,10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] {
    G & H \\
    G/\ker \varphi & \im \varphi \\
  };
 \path[-stealth, auto] (m-1-1) edge node[swap] {$q$}                  (m-2-1)
                               edge node       {$\varphi$}            (m-1-2)
                               edge node       {$\hat{\varphi}$}      (m-2-2)
                       (m-2-1) edge node[swap] {$\overline{\varphi}$} (m-2-2)
                       (m-2-2) edge[draw=none]
                                    node [sloped, auto=false,
                                     allow upside down] {$\subseteq$} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}
 G               \rar{\varphi} \dar[swap]{q}\drar{\hat\varphi}
   & H \\
 G/\ker\varphi   \rar[swap]{\overline\varphi}
   & \im \varphi \arrow[draw=none]{u}[sloped,auto=false]{\subseteq}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2

```
\documentclass[class=amsart,10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  edge node/.code={%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@tonodes\expandafter{\tikz@tonodes #1}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  subseteq/.style={
    draw=none,
    edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$\subseteq$}}},
  Subseteq/.style={
    draw=none,
    every to/.append style={
      edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$\subseteq$}}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]{
    G & H \\
    G/\ker \varphi & \im \varphi \\
  };
 \path[-stealth, auto] (m-1-1) edge node[swap] {$q$}                  (m-2-1)
                               edge node       {$\varphi$}            (m-1-2)
                               edge node       {$\hat{\varphi}$}      (m-2-2)
                       (m-2-1) edge node[swap] {$\overline{\varphi}$} (m-2-2)
                       (m-2-2) edge[subseteq]                         (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzcd}
 G               \rar{\varphi} \dar[swap]{q}\drar{\hat\varphi}
   & H \\
 G/\ker\varphi   \rar[swap]{\overline\varphi}
   & \im \varphi \arrow[Subseteq]{u}{}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image] [image]

Comment: Great, your answer has taught me far more than I asked. 
   For code 1, why did you add "allow upside down" to the special node? I see how it works for other examples, but here it doesn't seem to change anything.
   For code 2, what's happening in the first \tikzset? In the second \tikzset, what is the different between Subseteq and subseteq? I can tell "S" is used in tikzcd and "s" is used in tikzpicture.

Comment: @SimonStolarczyk When nodes are rotated by `sloped` they are usually rotated so that they are not upside down. This may confuse readers as the symbol will be oriented in a way that suggests the opposite. See this example: `\tikz[nodes=sloped]{\draw[->] (0,0) -- node {$\subseteq$} (-1,1);\draw[->] (1,0) -- node[allow upside down] {$\subseteq$} (0,1);}` (So you might still use the arrow and simply place `\subseteq` above/below it.) The option for an `tikz-cd` arrow is used as a path option, not as an option to `edge`/`to`. This is solved with the `every to` style.

Comment: What if my arrow is a diagonal arrow (like \arrow{dr}[Subset])? The code works for vertical arrows, but it keeps giving me an error for the diagonal case...