# Can a tikzcd arrow be replaced with another symbol?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'd like to put other symbols than arrows, e.g. a + sign, between the nodes of a `tikzcd` diagram. Is this possible?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216027/4427 help?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132007/replacing-an-arrow-with-an-inclusion-symbol-in-tikz

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks.

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes, thanks; also linked by egreg.